# STL Container for storing multiple types of values?

Tags: c++, stl, containers, std, message-bus

I have a `Message` structure that I am using with a message bus, and I'd like to send data with messages. The problem is that the data will vary in type; maybe for one message I'll just want to send one int, but for another I'll want to send several ints, a string, maybe even a pointer to an object for example. I *could* do something like this:

```
struct Message {
    std::map<int, int> intPayload;
    std::map<int, std::string> strPayload;
    short id;
};
```

But not only is this ugly and unclean, and probably wastes space, but that doesn't account for if I want to pass a relatively exotic data type like a pointer to an instance of a class for example. What should I be using for this?

Comment: Using inheritance and pointers to the base class and virtual functions?

Comment: My first guess would be polymorphism if possible in your situation.

Comment: @DeiDei I'm a bit confused, from my understanding polymorphism has to do with class/struct inheritance, how would polymorphism help here?

Comment: Or are both of you suggesting I make a `Message` struct, and a `MessageString` struct, and a `MessageStringNoInt` struct, etc etc??

Comment: If you know all of the possible types, `std::variant` or `boost::variant` is generally appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. Here's an example with C++17's `std::variant`:

```
std::vector<std::variant<int, std::string>> vec1;

vec1.emplace_back(1);
vec1.emplace_back("hello"s);

doSomethingWithInt( std::get<int>(vec1[0]) );
doSomethingWithString( std::get<std::string>(vec1[1]) );
```

`vec1` is a list of element that are either `int` or `std::string`.

You can also use a static visitor:

```
std::vector<std::variant<int, std::string>> vec2;

// ...

for(auto&& variant : vec1) {
    variant.visit([](auto value){
        using t = decltype(value);

        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<t, int>) {
            std::cout << "value is a int!" << std::endl;
        } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<t, std::string>) {
            std::cout << "value is a string!" << std::endl;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I suspect in his case he cannot say what's the type to get out from the variant within the class that handles the message.

Comment: This doesn't work in Visual Studio 2015 (I can't include `<variant>`), am I doing something wrong? Does it just not support C++17?

Comment: There are many way to know which type it is. The best method is through the method visit, get_if, and get. The documentation is quite complete. go check out the [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) page on cppreference

Comment: @Omega msvc don't support c++11 completely yet (missing expression sfinae). And VS 2015 has not finished their c++14 either. If you want modern C++, you're gonna need a modern compiler. The msvc team are doing great efforts to make it so, but hasn't finished yet. VS 2017 is doing much better in term of C++11/14/17.

Comment: I must admit that I like your solution. That said, C++17 isn't reality on modern compilers yet (still a working draft). If he's bound to MSVC, he'll be able to use `if constexpr` in 2027 (partially implemented or with fancy bugs). :-)

Comment: Modern compiler like? G++? All I know is VC++ and G++.

Comment: @Omega GCC 6 and clang 3.9 are really great.

Answer (score 2):

A simple example using inheritance and polymorphism:

```
struct MessageBase
{
    // The function to send *this* message to the receiver
    virtual void send(ReceiverClass*) = 0;
};

struct MessageInt : MessageBase
{
    int payload;

    void send(ReceiverClass* receiver)
    {
        // Code to send this message type to the receiver...
    }
};

struct MessageString : MessageBase
{
    std::string payload;

    void send(ReceiverClass* receiver)
    {
        // Code to send this message type to the receiver...
    }
};

// ...

// Vector to store the messages
std::vector<MessageBase*> messages;

// Add a couple of messages
messages.push_back(new MessageInt{123});
messages.push_back(new MessageString{"Foobar"});

// Send the message to some receiver
for (auto const* message : messages)
    message->send(some_reciver_object);
```

Any [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) should be able to give you more information.

Answer (score 2):

You can base your solution on the visitor pattern.
As a minimal, working example:

```
struct Listener;

struct Message {
    virtual void accept(Listener &) = 0;
};

struct SimpleMessage: Message {
    void accept(Listener &) override;
    int i;
};

struct ComplexMessage: Message {
    void accept(Listener &) override;
    int i;
    char c;
    double d;
};

struct Listener {
    void visit(SimpleMessage &) {}
    void visit(ComplexMessage &) {}
    void listen(Message &m) { m.accept(*this); }
};

void SimpleMessage::accept(Listener &l) { l.visit(*this); }
void ComplexMessage::accept(Listener &l) { l.visit(*this); }

struct Bus {
    Bus(Listener *l): l{l} {}
    void publish(Message &m) { l->listen(m); }
private:
    Listener *l;
};

int main() {
    Listener l;
    Bus b{&l};

    SimpleMessage sm;
    ComplexMessage cm;

    b.publish(sm);
    b.publish(cm);
}
```

Set aside the fact that the implementation for the `Bus` is trivial, note that `visit` member functions in `Listener` can be virtual.
This way, all your listener can be derived from that class and override the desired methods.
The `Bus` will accept a set of `Listener`s, no matter what's the actual derived type, and a generic `Message`. On the other side, message will promote itself to the right derived type and pass a reference to the given listener.

The technique behind the visitor pattern is also known as *double dispatching*, if you want to explore it further.