# Multiple data types linked list

Tags: c++

I am relatively new to c++ and have been trying to get used to the syntax.
I know data types must be known at the time of compiling but I want to create a linked list whose nodes can have different data types. For example index 1 has an integer key, index 2 a string key. Maybe not possible. Thanks!

Heres a lil snippet of what is going so far that can only handle one data type in the list.

```
template <typename T>
struct node{
  T key;
  node<T>* next;
  node<T>* previous;
};

template <class T>
class linkedList{
  public:
    linkedList();
    ~linkedList();

    void push(T key);
    void pop();
    //Add insert? insert ordered
    T get(int index);

    void print();

    void sort();

  private:
    node<T>* root;
    void push(T key, node<T>* n);
    void pop(node<T>* n);
    void destroy_list();
};
```

Comment: This is a very commonly-asked question. See, for instance, [this version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738405/how-can-i-store-objects-of-differing-types-in-a-c-container) that's over a decade old, or this [more recent one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41658482/stl-container-for-storing-multiple-types-of-values) that mentions `std::variant`.

Comment: @NathanPierson is right. One thing I wanna add, is that you could use either an union, or a void pointer.... But it's a really ugly trick

Comment: The answer is "you should not". There is very few places in C++ where an inhomogeneous container makes any sense, and I'm certain this is not one of them. Instead, you should rethink why you want that in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Given you're asking how to build your own container I'll try to explain why this can't be working the way I assume you think it should work, i.e. the `T` at index 0 should be `int` and and index 1 an `string` etc.

The compiler needs to define the data layout of the `node<T>` struct at compile time, so it has to know the concrete type of `T` at that point. So all nodes of `list<T>` will have the same storage layout and there's no way of storing a `string` in a variable of type `int`. Also, how should the compiler know what type `pop()` will return?

As pointed out in the comments, there are several ways to work around this, though. But strictly speaking the types of `key` will be all the same, either a `std::variant`, `std::any`, a `union`, a pointer to a polymorphic base class or even a `void*`.

If you want to dig into the concepts making these things possible, search for "type erasure" and, "(dynamic) polymorphism".

Lastly, I want to mention that if you know the exact sequence of types at compile time, you could use a `std::tuple<int, string, ...>`. But there's no way to change this sequence during runtime.